# Finding the angles in a right trapezoid

Tags: geometry

It's been a while since I took Geometry, apologies if this is obvious but I couldn't find an answer while searching. I have a right trapezoid:

[image: Right Trapezoid]

The sides a, b, and c are known. Can I find the remaining two angles given the information I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from  pedal triangle 
angle = $\pi/2+\arctan{\frac{c-b}{a}}$

Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You can use also law of cosine:

$${\left(\sqrt{a^2+c^2}\right)}^2=b^2+{\left(\sqrt{a^2+(c-b)^2}\right)}^2-2b\sqrt{a^2+(c-b)^2} \cos \alpha$$